# Can I simply "pass" the except block if I catch an error (I dont need to do anything within in it)? What is best practice?

Tags: python, exception, except

If I catch an error with "try" can I "pass" the "except" statement? Whats best practice?

From a get request I am receiving a dictionary which is a string and other times I am getting a string of html. So I am using a try statement to convert the string dictionary into a dictionary. I don't need to do anything if it catches an error trying to convert the response which isn't a string.

Comment: How do you tell the difference between a string dictionary and a string of html?

Comment: Generally, the rule of thumb is to never fail silently. However, in this case I think it is perfectly acceptable to `pass`.

Comment: user10987432 Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, this is perfectly fine. Often, it fits best with Python's "Ask Forgiveness, Not Permission" approach. Though, [as user10987432 says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666744/can-i-simply-pass-the-except-block-if-i-catch-an-error-i-dont-need-to-do-anyt#comment103636475_58666744), in many cases you might want to log the error to help you understand what happened later.

Answer (score 0):

Can you? Sure. There is nothing that says you have to do something with an error. You can fail silently. I guess the situation would dictate the reason why you might want to. I can't think of a situation off hand, but it's hard to speak in universals.

```
try:
    3/0
except:
    pass
print("Finished.")
```

Comment: Hey! I thought of a situation. Suppose you are writing an example code to show it can be done?